# Is it a fact that the city of Shimla is named after Goddess Shyamala?

Tags: history, goddess, india

Is it a fact that Shimla, the capital city of Himachal Pradesh is named after Goddess Shyamala?

What is the image of the Goddess?

Comment: "What is the image of the Goddess?" Goddess Shyamala looks like Goddess Matangi. Matangi is one of the 10 Mahavidyas. She is dark-complexioned that is why so-named.

Answer (score 3):

There is a controversy on the origin of the name Shimla. According to many, the capital town of Himachal Pradesh Shimla derive it's name from Goddess Shyamala.

[The official website](http://hpshimla.nic.in/sml_hist.htm#Shimla%20Town) of district administration, Shimla gives two stories for this origin.

> The name Shimla was derived from 'Shyamalaya' meaning   blue house said to be the name of house built of blue slate by a faqir on Jakhu. According to one version Shimla takes it name from 'Shamla' meaning a blue female another name for Goddess Kali. The place was on the Jakhu Hillside, there was a temple of Goddess Kali. During the British period the image of the Goddess was shifted to a new place ,now famous Kali Bari Temple.

This temple was originally near Jakhu hill but the British brought the idol of the Goddess to the new place. The present temple is built in 1845 A.D.

This temple is famous in Shimla. Hindus say this reason whereas muslims say the other reason. We can't deny that there is no role of the temple in the naming of a town. So, the temple of Shyamala devi could be a strong reason for the name of the town.

The image of the Goddess in the temple:

[image: goddess image in temple]

Image Source: From [this](http://www.simlakalibari.org/) website.

Shyamala devi is named such because she has a dark complexion.

For more details on Shyamala devi, see the below post.

[Who is Goddess Shyamala?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11052/who-is-goddess-shyamala)